# Is there an equivalent to getElementById but for looking INSIDE script tags?

Tags: javascript

I am used to using `document.getElementById` to find something very specific.

However I now want to find something that's inside script tags, when you go to "view source:

so, for example, for [this random product page](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0CRMCFCWB) you can "view source" and find (in page) `landingImageUrl":"`

```
<script type="a-state" data-a-state="{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;desktop-landing-image-data&quot;}">{"landingImageUrl":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41iuSZgmF2L.__AC_SX300_SY300_QL70_ML2_.jpg"}</script>
```

what I am looking for is that URL to a small image.

Can i do this programmatically?

- I suppose I could use a regular expression to get the image URL `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41iuSZgmF2L.__AC_SX300_SY300_QL70_ML2_.jpg` if I had downloaded the HTML file.
- Are there any other techniques I could use, even outside javascript, such as AppleScript ?

Comment: `document.querySelector('script[type="a-state"]')`, perhaps? What have you researched before posting? [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial.

Use a proper [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
const imageURL = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('script[type="a-state"]').textContent).landingImageUrl;
console.log(imageURL);
document.querySelector('img').src=imageURL;
```

```html
<script type="a-state" 
data-a-state="{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;desktop-landing-image-data&quot;}">{"landingImageUrl":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41iuSZgmF2L.__AC_SX300_SY300_QL70_ML2_.jpg"}
</script>

<img id="img">
```